# square root n limit

Tags: calculus, limits

$$(x_{n})_{n\geq 2}\ \ x_{n}=\sqrt[n]{1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}(k-1)(k-1)!} $$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{x_{n}}{n}=?$$

I'm trying to solve the sum I but I don't know how to rewrite it.Can you give me some hints?

edit:

The sum $\sum_{k=2}^{n}(k-1)(k-1)!$ should be $(n! - 1)$ so $x_{n}=\sqrt[n]{n!}$.The limit would be $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^{n}}}$ .If I use cauchy d'alembert criterion and make some simplifications I would get $e^{-1}$ (the right answer)My problem is that sum.How I obtain $n! - 1$ ?

Answer (score 5):

Very roughly, the sum will be dominated by the last term.  You can then apply Stiriling's approximation to the last term
$$(n-1)(n-1)!\approx \frac {(n-1)^n}{e^{n-1}}\sqrt {2\pi (n-1)}$$
The $n^{th}$ root of this goes to $\frac {n-1}e$ so the limit goes to $\frac 1e$
You need to justify the approximations made, particularly the one about considering only the last term of the sum.

Comment: Hi, thank you the response.The sum $\sum_{k=2}^{n}(k-1)(k-1)!$ should be $n! - 1$ so $x_{n}=\sqrt[n]{n!}$.The limit would be $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^{n}}}$ .If I use cauchy d'alembert criterion I would get $e^{-1}$ (the right answer)My problem is that sum.How I obtain $n! - 1$ ?

Comment: As Vladimir said, you should ask the question you have.  I would use induction.  Show it is true for $k=2$, which is easy, then assume it is true up to $k$ and show it holds for $k+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, using Stirling's formula $m!=(m/e)^m\sqrt{2\pi m}(1+o(1))$ as $m\to\infty$, we find that the radicand for large $k$ is $((n-1)/e)^{n-1} A_n$, where $1\le A_n\le Cn^{5/2}$ with some positive constant $C$ independent of $n$. Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{A_n}=1$, and we obtain
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n-1)^{(n-1)/n}}{ne^{(n-1)/n}}=\frac1e.
$$

Comment: Hi, thank you the response.The sum $\sum_{k=2}^{n}(k-1)(k-1)!$ should be $n! - 1$ so $x_{n}=\sqrt[n]{n!}$.The limit would be $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^{n}}}$ .If I use cauchy d'alembert criterion I would get $e^{-1}$ (the right answer)My problem is that sum.How I obtain $n! - 1$ ?

Comment: If that's your real problem, you should have written it in your question in the first place. We only try to answer questions posed and cannot generally read between the lines. Sorry, but I cannot be helpful further with your problem/

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(k-1)(k-1)!$ is very nearly $k(k-1)!$, which is $k!$. We'll use that:
$$
\sum_{k=2}^n (k-1)(k-1)! + \sum_{k=2}^n (k-1)! = \sum_{k=2}^n (k-1+1)(k-1)! = \sum_{k=2}^n k!
$$
Then (careful with the limits):
$$
\sum_{k=2}^n (k-1)(k-1)! = \sum_{k=2}^n k! - \sum_{k=2}^n (k-1)! = \sum_{k=2}^n k! - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k! = n! - 1! \tag{*}
$$
because almost all the terms cancel out.

---

**Edit**: neater train of thought, but technically the same:
Observe that $(k-1)(k-1)! = k! - (k-1)!$, and then follow with $(*)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)